# How to make a given LaTeX template compatible with my LyX file?

Tags: lyx, templates

I have already written my entire thesis in LyX. But my university has a fixed LaTeX format in which I've to turn my thesis in. Kindly advise.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, however you need to give us some clues. You need to change the commands that rely of the class that you are using to match the class the university supplies, but since you have not given any information about either, there is nothing we can say.

Comment: Note also that, IIRC, LyX has a LaTeX export option.  It may very well be easiest to apply the change to the LaTeX file itself, rather than running through LyX's interface.

Comment: My advice is to ask a question rather than demand the community tell you what to do...Sorry, that was mean.  But "Kindly advise" has a connotation of entitlement and everyone is a volunteer here. Help us help you.

Answer (score 4):

*The question is general so is my answer.*

**Assumptions - less likely**

- you have finished your document (e.g., thesis) and will **not** change your document much;

  ... AND ...
- you know roughly about LaTeX, BibTeX, Makeidx etc.;

*Suggestion:*
The fastest way to use the required LaTeX styles is to export all your LyX documents to LaTeX. It might be safer to create a new directory and copy all the LaTeX file, pictures, and everything what you need to build your PDF there. Then edit and adjust my LaTeX such that the required template is used.

*Warning:*
If you have to edit your document later on, you need to edit the LaTeX file directly or it might be error-prone to re-export your changed LyX document .

**Assumptions - more likely**

- you have not completely finished your document and probably will have to edit some parts;

  ... OR ...
- the LaTeX template is simple (e.g., just a style file and not a class file);

Still you need to know about LaTeX a bit. Maybe read ["A (Not So) Short Introduction to LaTeX"](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/) or similar...

*Suggestion:* Copy the settings from the main LaTeX file of your LaTeX template (and possibly further configuration files) into the LaTeX preamble of LyX. Note the LyX provides quite a lot of setting via "Document setttings". Hence, instead of copying code to the LaTeX Preamble use the corresponding LyX settings.

Note that for LaTeX files of your LaTeX template that hardly need to be changed by you (for example, a LaTeX file which contains the title page) you can just include them into LyX by "Insert > File > Child document" (then use "Include" or "Input" as was used in the LaTeX template).

You can also try to import a LaTeX file into LyX via "File > Import". If it straight compiles afterwards then fine. But be aware that quite concealed errors can occur sometimes.

(It will get more difficult when your LaTeX template provides non-standard environments that are to be used for things like tables or figures.)